# Emulate /proc folder

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, docker, proc

I've a software that uses a few nasty algorithms to determine, wether it runs in a docker container or not. One example is, that it scans `/proc/1/cgroup` for non root paths (i.e. `/docker/SOME-UUID` instead of `/` behind a group name)

My question is, if it is possible, to inject a fake `/proc/1/cgroup` (or similar files) file into the process to circumvent the check?

I've thought about using chroot, but would be interested, if there are nicer alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bind mount for that:

```
mount --bind /replacement/file /proc/1/cgroup
```

That should be done within the container name space.

Comment: But isn't there a chance, that the whole system would break down with that? Or am I misunderstanding the importance of the proc folder for the system?

You're answer has let me down the path of  namespace mount points. It's very clever. Thanks

Comment: @GeorgFriedrich If you do not limit that mount to the container mount namespace then it may have undesirable side-effects, yes. But as the configuration of PID 1 is probably neither read nor changed I do not assume problems to be probable.

Comment: Ah tanks. Great answer